# UITablecontroller and UIViewController issues - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am new here and to coding and I need some help with a project that I'm currently stuck on.

I have built an app containing UITableView that first displays body areas (Gastro, cardio, respiratory, etc), the second displays more detailed features on the first (in gastro the table will display stomach, small intestine, colon, etc) and then the the UIViewController will have the more detailed info on the stomach etc.

I have this working all ok but one problem has arose. The UIViewController, regardless of which option is selected in the first table, displays the same info, i.e I get results for gastro even after selecting cardio etc.

The UIviewcotrollers have the storyboards identifiers G1, G2 etc as shown in 'Subchapters' under identities.
I want G1 and the rest of the G series to only display gastro info and then create new view controllers for cardio, C1, C2 etc and so on for the rest of the chapters.

Below is my code. I hope someone could help with this. I would really appreciate it!

```
import UIKit

class Chapters: UITableViewController {

var ChaptersArray = [String]()

var SubchaptersArray = [secondTable]()





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    // chapter names

    ChaptersArray = ["Gastrointestinal","Cardiovascular","Respiratory","Central Nervous System", "Infections"]


    // subcharpter names

    SubchaptersArray =  [secondTable(SecondTitle: ["Gas1", "Gas2", "Gas3", "Gas4"]),
                         secondTable(SecondTitle: ["Card1", "Card2", "Card3", "Card4"]),
                         secondTable(SecondTitle: ["Res1", "Res2", "Res3", "Res4"])]





}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as  UITableViewCell!


cell.textLabel?.text = ChaptersArray[indexPath.row]




return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ChaptersArray.count
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! Subchapters

    var secondTableArrayTwo : secondTable

    secondTableArrayTwo = SubchaptersArray[indexPath.row]

    destViewController.SubChaptersArray = secondTableArrayTwo.SecondTitle








}
```

}

```
import UIKit

class Subchapters: UITableViewController {

var SubChaptersArray = [String]()

var identities = [String]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    identities = ["G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"]




}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return SubChaptersArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell") as  UITableViewCell!

    cell.textLabel?.text = SubChaptersArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]

    let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: true)

}




}
```

I have searched google and here for an answer but could find nothing to help, so any explanations as to how to fix this problem would be great and much appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: I think there is some problem with your segue connection. Why don't you try to push ViewController programmatically?

Comment: @vishal Yes more than likely there is, but what I'm not sure. How would I do it programmatically?

Comment: Push it like this :  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Your_ViewController_Object, animated: true)

Comment: Cool thanks for the help, I will try this later and let you know if it works, away from my computer now unfortunately

Comment: @VishalSonawane I just checked my code and I already have the code you mentioned in the second tableviewController above. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Re you getting correct viewController on table view cell click?

Comment: For gastro (The first cell in table 1) every thing works perfectly. The issue is that when I select cardio, or resp (Options 2&3 in table 1) they return the same answers as gastro. I want to be able to have cardio and resp return a different set of results. Does that make sense?

Comment: @VishalSonawane Any Suggestions?

Comment: your identities array contains values only for gastro i.e G!,G@ etc..So every time identities[indexPath.row] will return you one of those values for gastro only. You will have to create separate arrays for cardio and resp and then access them on your 2,3 options in tableView.

Comment: @VishalSonawane ok perfect thank you, I have created the arrays for the other values, but can figure out how to be able to choose the array specific for the cell. I have checked online on different sites but can't find the solution. Would you know of a solution to get it to work? Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Are your number of cells constant? I mean will there be exact number of cells in a table view?

Comment: yes, once the app is created it won't change or be changed by a user for example

Comment: then try to use switch like this in didClick method var vcName = ""
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            {
                 vcName = identities1[indexPath.row]
            }
        case 1:
            {
                vcName = identities2[indexPath.row]
            }
        default: break
          
        }

Comment: When you say didClick method, do you mean didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: yeah..sorry for typo.

Comment: @VishalSonawane I tried what you suggested above. I couldn't get it to work. Im not sure it would be the correct solution either? Im adding it to the subchapters file? is that right?

Comment: If possible can you share your code ?? So that I can run and find the solution.Because its being complicated now.

Comment: Yeah that would be great. I Will try upload it now

Comment: @VishalSonawane I uploaded the project to drop box and here is the link. Not sure if that is the best way to do it tho? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7f3q60fk7058qtj/AABRuIsSEpUvjuX8XVRxPIkJa?dl=0

Comment: Ok let me check. I will come back to you once I go through it.

Comment: You have written nothing on didSelectCell. What exactly you want to happen there??You have neither created any viewControllers to display details.

Comment: I have uploaded zip with some changes . Have a look at that and let me know. Here is the link: https://app.box.com/s/pxjynuiz47at73esqd8o2x1gnck5njbe

Comment: The View controllers are located on the main.storyboard with IDs as G1, G2, G3, G4

Comment: Perfect thank you, I will take a look over them now

Comment: @VishalSonawane I have had a look at the file that you uploaded. I have not been able to make it work though. I think I really need to sit down with someone face to face and work through my code! Thanks again for your help

Comment: When I run your code with the suggested changes, it returns a SIGABRT error